# Identity Server Partial Login and get the Email Claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

I have a partial login before navigating to a different page before full login occurs. Is there a way to obtain claims within the partial login intermediary page? For example, the email claim.

Within my controller, I can obtain the partial login with the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment.GetIdentityServerPartialLoginAsync()
```

Unfortunately, the Claims property on the returned object is always empty until a full login has been completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out claims aren't present for a partial login. I was able to obtain them from a `UserService` when composing an `AuthenticateResult` for Partial Logins.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you issue the partial login, there's an overload on the `AuthenticateResult` ctor where you can pass claims. These will be available in the partial login page via `GetIdentityServerPartialLoginAsync`.